# Teiid Redshift Translator does not support some of the Redshift SQL constructs

Tags: teiid, redhat-datavirt

I have configured a redshift datasource in teiid using redshift traslator. But some of the SQL functions in redshift doesn't have support when using with teiid. for an example I get the fallowing error when deploying the VDB

```
TEIID30068 The function 'nvl2(v_skey, c_skey, s_key)' is an unknown form.  Check that the function name and number of arguments is correct.
11/29/2017 12:13:01 PM[Server:server-one] 06:43:01,886 WARN  [org.teiid.RUNTIME] (Worker25_async-teiid-threads41) TEIID40073 The metadata for the VDB ReportRedshift.1 is loaded, however it is not valid. Check models for errors to correct the metadata and re-deploy: ReportRedshift
```

some other Redshift SQL constructs like 'ISNULL' also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like NVL2 is not yet exposed as a pushdown function and is not a Teiid system function.  You may work around that by defining the function on your physical model, however to be strongly typed you'd have to add a variant for every type signature that you need.  Otherwise you'd need to submit an enhancement request - https://issues.jboss.org/projects/TEIID

What do you mean ISNULL is not working?  Are you talking about a function or the IS NULL predicate?

Comment: I was talking about the ISNULL function. I was able to write sql query in a different way without using those functions. Thanks a lot for the reply